# Objective c - How to check if the photo metadata has been changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, metadata, photo

I am developing in-House iOS app with objective-c for capturing images and I'm depending on photos metadata to get the correct locations and dates, but the new iOS versions allow the user to adjusting and changing the whole photo information, and our field staff able to changing the photo metadata with fake details.

The only ways that can protect the informations:
1- How to check the photo if metadata has changed or not, and refuse the modified photo.?
2- It possible to create configuration file to make all photos with read-only?

Answer (score 0):

The photo library, accessible through the Photos app, belongs to the user — not to you. So if you don't want the user to have normal powers over these photos, then don't store them in the *user's photo library*.

Comment: That's right, but our users are using the Photos app because they have to write a report on every photo taken as a case study, and it's going to take a long time during fieldwork, so they're working when they get home.

Comment: Sure, if the user uses the Camera app, it's out of your hands. But if your app _takes_ the photo, your app can _store_ the photo (or at least its original metadata) wherever you like. Basically you create your own photo filing system and reference it when the user constructs the report for submission. I've worked on apps that behave this way. However, _that is not what you asked_. I answered, correctly I believe, the question you _did_ ask.

Answer (score 0):

With other objects on iOS (I'm thinking of contacts in particular) you can store metadata of your own in Apple's database. I don't think that's the case with photos, sorry.

You could perhaps require your users take the photo in your app and store the location in a database of your own. You might be able to store the photo in the photos database if that's something you want.

Comment: That's right, but our users are using the Photos app because they have to write a report on every photo taken as a case study, and it's going to take a long time during fieldwork, so they're working when they get home

Comment: Maybe you could provide your own reportless photo collection in-app and disable import from Apple's library. (I know just getting the real location of a photo would be better, but I don't know a way.)